# Transcendence of $e^{i\pi\alpha}$ when $\alpha$ is irrational

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is is true that $e^{i\pi\alpha}$ is transcendental whenever  $\alpha$ is irrational? And if so is there a simple proof?

Comment: No, $e^{i\pi}=-1$, therefore $e^{i\pi\alpha}=(e^{i\pi})^{\alpha}=(-1)^{\alpha}$.

Comment: @barakmanos $(e^{i\pi})^{\alpha} \neq e^{i\pi \alpha}$ in general. Even so, then what? $(-1)^{\alpha} :=\exp(\alpha \log (-1)) = e^{i \pi \alpha}$, back to the starting point.

Comment: $e^{i\pi\alpha}$ is transcendental if $\alpha$ is algebraically and irrational. This can be proofed with Gelfond-Schneiders theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No:  try $\alpha = \dfrac{\tan^{-1} 0.75}{\pi} \approx 0.204832764699\ldots$.

Then $e^{i\pi\alpha}=0.8 + 0.6i$